# Java, достать данные из строки

Tags: java, строки

Имеется строка

```
24 Example 62.34 7
```

Нужно достать из этого все, что идет после первого числа:

```
Example 62.34 7
```

Comment: Я вам уже ответил в вашем предыдущем вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Можно разными способами. Например регулярками. Но, если после первого числа у вас всегда идёт пробел, то можно просто строку по пробелу на массив разбить и отбросив первый элемент собрать заново:

```
String input = "24 Example 62.34 7";
String[] array = input.split(" ");
String result = "";

for(int i = 1; i<array.lenght; i++)
{
    result += array[i];
    if(i != array.lenght-1) result+=" ";
}
```